# How long is "as long as possible" in wp_cache_set()?

Tags: multisite, database, cache, customization

The [documentation for `wp_cache_set()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cache_set) says that if you pass in 0 for `$expire` (which is also the default), then it is cached for "as long as possible". How long is this? What determines it? Are we talking hours, days?

In my case: I have a *very* expensive SQL query on a multisite network of literally 100s of blogs, the result of which could be cached for weeks (really forever - could just manually flush it when needed). Should I use WordPress's cache or sort something out myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WordPress object cache isn't a persistent cache, it's meant to cache data within a single page load, so "as long as possible" will never be longer than a single request.

Use the [Transients API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) if you want to store your data across multiple page loads, or even simpler, just store it in an option manually.

Comment: +1 from me. Additional alternative is to use a plugin that convert wp object cahe in persistent cache using APC, memchache or similar. [This is one](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tribe-object-cache/)

Comment: Thanks for the info, makes sense. Apparently our heavily hacked/customized WP installation is already converting this cache into something persistent, because for me the cache is still there across multiple requests. Guess I need to dig into our venerable codebase to answer my question on this system...

Comment: It can be persistent if you plug in a replacement for example for Redis.

Comment: Also some hosts (like WPEngine) have object cache built into their service